# C# repository and inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, repository

I have inheritance defined `A->B->C`. Currently, I'm using repository pattern without generics. Please note, I cannot have a common CRUD operations in base class.

My questions:

1) Should we define a repository for each class?

2) How will I do a `save` and a `get` from the bottommost child object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Generic Repo or create virtual method at base class so that the child class can override.